# Optional<T> does not handle null elements

Tags: java-8, java-stream

As I experimented `Optional<T>` does not handle `null` elements, so in the following example it throws a `NullPointerException` in the last statement:

```
List<String> data = Arrays.asList("Foo", null, "Bar");
data.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
data.stream().skip(1).findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

So, I still have to explicitly deal with `null` and filter non-null elements, such as:

```
data.stream()
    .filter(item -> item != null)
    .skip(1)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Is there any alternative that avoids dealing explicitly with null as: `item != null`

Comment: Avoid storing nulls in the list? I can't remember a single use-case where I thought that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do.  If you want to treat `null` as a valid value, the answer is different than if you want to skip nulls.

If you want to keep "nulls" in your stream:

```
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList("Foo", null, "Bar");
    data.stream().map(Optional::ofNullable).findFirst().flatMap(Function.identity()).ifPresent(System.out::println);  ;
    data.stream().map(Optional::ofNullable).skip(1).findFirst().flatMap(Function.identity()).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

If you want to remove nulls from your stream, use `data.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)` to filter it out (or as you stated `o -> o != null`, whatever you prefer.

Comment: The `flatMap` with the identity `Function` is the trick that I was missing

Comment: @MiguelGamboa, the `flatMap` basically changes it from an `Optional<Optional<String>>` to just an `Optional<String>`, which is what you really wanted at that point.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` using the method [`Objects.nonNull(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) added for this purpose.

There is no way to avoid explicit filtering, unless you avoid having `null`s in your source list in the first place.

Note that it would be strange if the `Optional` handled the `null` in this case as it would yield an empty optional which had the semantic of “there is no first element” which implies “the stream was empty” which is just wrong.

Dealing with `null`s explicitly is the cleanest solution here as it also allows you to explicitly tell whether you want `.filter(Objects::nonNull).skip(1)`, `.skip(1).filter(Objects::nonNull)`…

…or `.map(s->s==null? "null-replacement": s).findFirst()`